# Spring boot - JSP Rendering issue in Jboss 6.4

Tags: spring, jboss, spring-boot

I have a simple Spring boot application that is deployed to Jboss 6.4. But the JSP renders as text: Here are some details about the application:

1. Pom file dependencies

   ```
       <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       <exclusions>
       <exclusion>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
       <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
       <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
       <version>2.5</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. WebMvcConfig File has the following method:

   ```
     import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
     import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
     import   org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
     import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
     import   rg.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
     import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
   public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
       DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
   configurer.enable();
    }

      @Bean

    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {

   InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
   resolver.setViewClass(org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView.class);
   resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/jsp/");
   resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
   return resolver;
   }
   ```

JSP File:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"  prefix="spring"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c" %>
    <html>
    <head>
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    </head>
    <body> 
 Message: Test Message
   </body> 
  </html>
```

But once deployed and accessed via Jboss here is what is displayed on the screen:

<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%> <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c" %> <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> Message: Test Message

Please let me know if any of you have come across issues with Spring Boot deployment into jboss and if there is any workaround.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There's no need for you own view resolver bean if you're using Spring Boot. Also, what's in the rest of your `WebMvcConfig` class?

Comment: Andy..I have edited and added the entire WebMvcCofig method above. Please take a look.

Comment: Typically speaking, you shouldn't use `@EnableWebMvc` in a Spring Boot app as it disables all of the auto-configuration of Spring MVC. That almost certainly isn't what you want here.

Comment: Andy,  Thank you for your response. I tried another simple application without @EnableWebMvc , but now I get a 404 error (when the war file is deployed to Jboss). Am I missing anything ?  I have my JSP inside WEB-INF/views folder and my application.properties file look like this :                                                                      spring.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views
spring.view.suffix=.jsp
server.servlet-path=/*  . Also may be this is worth mentioning. I was able to render a thymeleaf template file successfully in Jboss.